# conversion code with int pointers

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void readFile(FILE *file);
void count (FILE *file, int *alpha, int *digit, int *punct, int *spaces);
void printMessage(int *alpha, int *digit, int *punct, int *spaces);

int main( void ) {
FILE *file = NULL;
readFile(file);
return 0;
}

void readFile(FILE *file) {
file = fopen("/Users/AdmiralDanny/Desktop/testFile.txt", "r");
int *alpha = NULL, *digit = NULL, *punct = NULL, *space = NULL;
if (file) {
  count(file, alpha, digit, punct, space);
  fclose(file);
} else {
  perror( "error opening the file" );
}
}

void count (FILE *file, int *alpha, int *digit, int *punct, int *spaces) {
  int ch;

 while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF ) {
   if (isalpha(ch) != 0) {
  ++alpha;
  } else if (isdigit(ch)) {
  ++digit;
  } else if (ispunct(ch)) {
  ++punct;
  } else if (isspace(ch)) {
    ++spaces;
  }
}
 printMessage(alpha, digit, punct, spaces);
}

void printMessage(int *alpha, int *digit, int *punct, int *spaces) {
printf( "alphabetic characters: %d\n", alpha );
printf( "digit characters: %d\n", digit);
printf( "punctuation characters: %d\n", punct );
printf( "whitespace characters: %d\n", spaces );
}
```

my .txt file only has 4 spaces and 12 alphabet character, but it gives me 48 alphabetic characters and 8 white space characters? why is this happening?
also, i get a warning when i tried to print out the int pointeres in printMessage method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No memory has been allocated for any of the `int`s and the `count()` function is just incrementing the `int` pointers not an `int` value:

```
++spaces; /* spaces is an int* so this increments the pointer. */
```

You could use `malloc()`, but it would simpler to stack allocate and pass the addresses in.

```
int alpha = 0, digit = 0, punct = 0, space = 0;
count(file, &alpha, &digit, &punct, &space);
```

and in `count()`:

```
(*spaces)++;
```

dereference the `int`s for incrementing and dereference for printing:

```
printf( "whitespace characters: %d\n", *spaces);
```

As the caller of `count()` does not require the updated values of the `int`s, just pass by value and forget about pointers altogether (same for `printMessage()`).

Comment: is this why, its printing 4 times more character than usual?

Comment: if i do count(file, &alpha, &digit, &punct, &space);, how come i get error "incompatible pointer types passing "int **" to paramenter of type 'int *' remove &

Comment: @dannyhuang, you need to change the type of the variables from `int*` to `int`, as illustrated in this answer.

Comment: `*spaces++;` increments the pointer (and evaluates to the value pointed to before the increment). You meant `++*spaces;` (or `(*spaces)++;` if you must use post-increment) to increment the pointed-to value.

Answer (score 0):

you can print address what pointer points to:

```
printf( "alphabetic characters: %p \n", alpha );
```

if you want just the value:

```
printf( "alphabetic characters: %d\n", *alpha );
```

same as *digit, *punct ....

Comment: if i put pointers before my int while printing them. It gives me a bad excess crash

Comment: first, reference them to pure integers and dont increment address. increment only values